# OpenGL Texture Showing Wired Lines instead of solid color

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, imgui

My Code

```
void SetPixel(int x, int y)
{
        unsigned char* offset = mImageData + (x + mImageHeight * y) * sizeof(unsigned char) * 3;
        offset[0] = 255;
        offset[1] = 0;
        offset[2] = 0;

}
```

And

```
 for (int j = imageHeight - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
        {
           SetPixel(i, j);
        }
     }
```

OpengL code:

Create:
m_InternalFormat = GL_RGB8;
m_DataFormat = GL_RGB;
m_Data = new unsigned char[width * height * 3];

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_RendererID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Set Data:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID);

    if(alpha)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    else
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Now i should get a Red Texture but i am getting :

[image: Screenshot]

See The top left corner. The texture is wrong.

I think this might be due to not setting the correct pixel offset. But i cant figure out exactly what is wrong ? Please Help.

Comment: Impossible to say answer without more context but at the very least I think `(x + mImageHeight * y)` should be `(x + mImageWidth * y)`?

Comment: @G.M. `(x + mImageWidth * y)` gives same lines but this time its the full texture instead of half. And this is all the code related to creating texture data

Comment: Then you really need to show how you are using the generated texture data.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @G.M. all i do with the data is   `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`

Comment: And how are the texture data/coordinates etc. used by your shader program?  Sorry, but there's a lot of code missing.

Comment: @G.M. none of that is managed by me all is done by IMGUI

Comment: @Rabbid76 cause i dont think this error has anything to do with imgui but rather with how i am setting the data for the texture as textures i load from files are working

Comment: @Rabbid76 i already told only 1 opengl call used to upload texture data to GPU. `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);` and how i generate textures, ... is just regular way and i didnot include them as i am able to properly use textures i load from files

Comment: @Rabbid76 yeah `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`  is working thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default OpenGL assumes that the start of each row of an image is aligned to 4 bytes. This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4. Since the image has 3 color channels (`GL_RGB`), and is tightly packed the size of a row of the image may not be aligned to 4 bytes.
When a RGB image with 3 color channels is loaded to a texture object and 3*width is not divisible by 4, [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) has to be set to 1, before specifying the texture image with `glTexImage2D`:

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```